# several instances of apache2

Tags: xubuntu, apache2, owncloud-server

I have recently setup xubunutu 14.04 on my computer, today I noticed there are several instances of apache2 running on my computer here is the list

[image]

Before this I only installed owncloud server,

Is it possible to find out as to why these different instances of apache2 are running by looking some configuration file to identify the package which are making it run ?
I recently installed owncloud server and this it started happening..

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache2 instances keep growing with page refreshes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/522527/apache2-instances-keep-growing-with-page-refreshes)

Comment: I think that is not the same question. when a page refreshes, it should drop the old process and start a new process on the server side. The link above is referring to a server that is misbehaving.
actually, That user was given misinformation. That behaviour isn’t normal.

Answer (score 0):

Those are instances where your webpage is open some place. I wouldn't worry about it. Every time someone (or something) opens a page on your webserver, that process will start. The process wont tell you who (outside of www-data) is accessing your page. But, your Apache server logs will. when the pages get closed, those processes will clear. 
you can try this answer for yourself:
do:

```
ps -ef  | grep apache2 | wc -l
```

then open a browser and go to your website.
then re run

```
ps -ef  | grep apache2 | wc -l
```

you should see the number increase.
then close your browser. and run

```
ps -ef  | grep apache2 | wc -l
```

the number will go down again, provided your don't get more traffic in the mean time.

At this point, you might be asking yourself, if Apache2 spawns a new process, each time a web page is accessed, wouldn't my system be prone to loading if numerous persons were accessing my page simultaneously? The answer is yes, that does happen, but you need thousands of concurrent connections before it becomes a problem. If you do experience those issues, switch to nginx which handles threads in a way that doesn't create multiple concurrent processes.

To have a look at who is accessing your page(s), read logs (access and error) in:
/var/log/apache2/

Answer (score 0):

do this:

`dpkg -l | grep apache2`

with this you can read your modules installed.

apache2 by default install the prefork mpm. this is needed because several extensions (mod_php for owncloud) are not thread safe and will go better with this module. Yo can try the worker mpm that is based in threads, but for php programs you need to reconfigure your server and not use mod_php, use fastcgi (php-fpm)